# 'GenModel cannot be resolved' errors

Tags: eclipse-plugin, eclipse-emf, emf, xcore

Suddenly there are build error in all of my Xcore model files. I don't know what I changed in my projects to deserve this.

The error message is the one in the title of the post:

`GenModel cannot be resolved.`

The errors are from the `GenModel` annotation on the package declarations of the XCore files:

```
@GenModel(modelDirectory="/com.organisation.project/src-gen")
package com.organisation.project.package;
```

#### Details

- The plug-ins do specify the `org.eclipse.emf.ecore.xcore.lib` required bundle. PDE reports no errors for the require bundle clause in the manifest file.
- The *Target Platform State* view in Eclipse contains the `org.eclipse.emf.ecore.xcore.lib` bundle.
- If I add the following line in the Xcore files then the build errors disappear:

  ```
  annotation "http://www.eclipse.org/emf/2002/GenModel" as GenModel
  ```
- Xcore SDK version: 1.4.0
- EMF SDK version: 2.12.0
- Eclipse for RCP and RAP Developers version: 4.6.2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I had this problem because Eclipse was confused about the target platform somehow.

Possibly the reason was that I had the EMF source code project opened in my workspace. When I closed them Eclipse did not understand that it again had to used EMF from the target platform.

Setting the target platform to *Running Platform*, then setting it back again resolved the issue. (The same technique that is recommended at [Vogella](https://www.vogella.com/tutorials/EclipseTargetPlatform/article.html#solving-potential-issues-with-your-target-definition).)